# how to name the output dataframe generated by python-ply

Tags: python

How can I name the data frame generated by the following code?

```
import re
import os
import csv
import codecs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as p
import pdb
import pandas as pd
from pandas_ply import install_ply, X, sym_call

install_ply(pd)



(data_merged
    .groupby('index')
    .ply_select(
        count = X.index.count(),
        p_avg = X.item_price.mean()
        ))
```

Comment: sorry pandas-ply i meant

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, I assume that you mean to name the output variable of the dataframe, which would be `data_out` in the following:

```
data_out = (data_merged
                .groupby('index')
                .ply_select(
                    count = X.index.count(),
                    p_avg = X.item_price.mean()
                )
           )
```

Note that this is not actually giving the DataFrame a name, it's just naming the variable. You could create another variable that holds a reference to `data_out` (a pointer) that would have a different name. This is true because `data_out` is a mutable object.

Series are named and its name is stored in the `name` attribute. DataFrames are not named, but their columns are, since they are Series.